# Inconsistent results with user that has user and groupid 0

Tags: linux, fedora

I have several users on a fedora 6 server that have user and group id 0, but some apps are somehow resolving the users differently:

```
[first_admin@server ~]# whoami
first_admin
[first_admin@server ~]# whoami
second_admin
```

`id -a` gives similar random results, so my question is what could be happening here?

Comment: The users all have the same user ID?

Comment: yes, and I have the same setup on another server which does resolve it to root always